# TCPDF Rotated text in table header over spilling

Tags: php, tcpdf

I'm rotating the headers in a table by 90 degress but cannot figure out how to locate them within the containing cell and have it be resized around them.

```
        $html .= '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color: #CCC;">';
    foreach ($fields as $field) {
        $html .= '<th>'
            . '<tcpdf method="StartTransform"/>'
            . '<tcpdf method="Rotate" params="' . $pdf->serializeTCPDFtagParameters(array(90)) .'"/>'
            . s($this->format_column_heading($field, true))
            . '<tcpdf method="StopTransform"/>'
            . '</th>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
```

The output ends up looking like:
[image]

Now I can use TranslateY to shift the headers down by a fixed amount but the column labels are user defined so that won't really help. I also don't understand how to persuade the greyed header cell to expand to wrap around the rotated header.

Note - This is a change to a mature and complex bit of PDF rendering code so I can't just rewrite to skip the html->pdf conversion.